# Ext.XTemplate loop through object

Tags: object, loops, extjs, extjs4.1

my controller returns data like this:

```
{
   "success":true,
   "data":{
      "35":{
         "msg":{
            "32":{
               "module_id":"35",
               "alert_id":"32",
               "alert_datetime":"2012-11-28 16:19:19",
               "param1_type":"imo",
               "param1_value":"453465",
               "param2_type":"",
               "param2_value":"0",
               "param3_type":"",
               "param3_value":"0",
               "msg":"triiiis dve",
               "count":1
            },
            "33":{
               "module_id":"35",
               "alert_id":"33",
               "alert_datetime":"2012-10-28 00:00:00",
               "param1_type":"imo",
               "param1_value":"54984",
               "param2_type":"",
               "param2_value":"0",
               "param3_type":"",
               "param3_value":"0",
               "msg":"triis tri",
               "count":1
            }
         }
      },
      "42":{
         "msg":{
            "1":{
               "module_id":"42",
               "alert_id":"1",
               "alert_datetime":"2012-10-28 16:19:19",
               "param1_type":"imo",
               "param1_value":"9281906",
               "param2_type":"",
               "param2_value":"0",
               "param3_type":"",
               "param3_value":"0",
               "msg":"",
               "count":1
            }
         }
      },
      "39":{
         "msg":{
            "2":{
               "module_id":"39",
               "alert_id":"2",
               "alert_datetime":"2012-10-28 12:36:31",
               "param1_type":"imo",
               "param1_value":"65464546",
               "param2_type":"",
               "param2_value":"0",
               "param3_type":"",
               "param3_value":"0",
               "msg":"",
               "count":1
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

After that I do this

```
that.tpl.overwrite(that.el, Ext.decode(response).data);
```

The problem is that I can't loop through the result object keys... I know how to loop through objects with pre-defined key names, but mine are dynamicaly generated...
Will appreciate some help, thanks!

Comment: have you seen [XTemplate](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.XTemplate) documentation? There is `foreach` keyword that loops through object's properties

Comment: Yes I read the documentation but the foreach is not working correctly... '<tpl foreach="msg">', just makes one loop for key "msg" instead 3 or 2 how its in my case...

Comment: Huh, the `foreach` method is only supported in 4.1.2 version which currently is only for support customers: [forum link](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?242048-Ext-JS-4.1.2-(GA)-Now-Available-Support-Only)

Comment: True story Alex. The problem is still here.. in other words - I don't know how to deal with nested loops (3 or more).. in this for loop there is nothing like $key=>$value ... FUUU

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you have an idea of the depth of nesting (4 levels below the "data" element in this case):

You could loop through the data with [Ext.Object.each](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.Object-method-each) (maybe there are some query methods for this too, not sure), looping through each element's children too. In case you use Ext.data.Model instances, you can use the Ext.data.association links to loop through the data.

In that case you could make a different template for each level and insert the result of each template in the template of the level above.

It sounds more difficult than it actually is I think.

foreach in templates is currently indeed only available for support subscribers.